# Object Not Found with Auto Archive pst file in Outlook

Tags: outlook-2003, outlook

When I try to do anything with the Auto Archive in outlook, I get an error message that says object not found.  This includes trying to get properties, or remove it.

I tried going into mail in the control panel, deleting her profile, and creating a new one.  This has not worked.  Anyone know what do when this happens?  I saw a webpage about ghost psts, but at the end it says this does not apply to archive.pst files.

Comment: BTW- just added links to the Outlook command line reference pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting Outlook from the command line with the `/cleanprofile` switch.  Not 100% sure that this will do anything that blowing out the profile didn't.

If that doesn't work, try it instead with the `/firstrun` switch which will start Outlook as if it were run for the first time.  Most likely you've got a bad path buried in the registry, this should cleanse the registry of it.

BTW- Here are the Outlook command line reference pages: [**Outlook 2003**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP010031101033.aspx), [**Outlook 2007**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/hp012185891033.aspx)

Comment: /cleanprofile did it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: `/cleanprofile` is not available in Outlook 2013 https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-2013-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6 . Any ideas on that?